# Extending an observable in a custom binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I have a custom binding handler that I am binding to a complex object in my view model.

The binding handler works correctly and the `update` function is called when any of the observable's properties update. However, the `update` function is called for *every* updated property, leading to odd behaviour since I am relying on the entire object to be available and up to date.

I understand why this is happening, as each property is causing an update to be called, and I think I know how to prevent this - by using the [deferred updates](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html) functionality of Knockout.

However, I am unable to find how to enable deferred updates just for the observable in my custom binding. I do not want to enable it application wide as I am writing the binding as a library function.

I have tried many different methods including:

- trying to extend the binding handler itself;
- extending the `init` function;
- extending the `valueAccessor`;
- [replacing the `valueAccessor` with a new observable with `deferred` applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571075/a-custom-bindinghandlers-return-value-observable);
- [creating a computed observable and rebinding the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643455/knockout-js-extending-value-binding-with-interceptor);

All of which have not worked.

I have not found any other custom binding handler that comes remotely close to this sort of function and have been trying to piece it together from other functions.

My binding code itself is relatively simple, I am taking the bound object and simply splitting out the parameters and passing them to a Code Mirror instance.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.editor = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var observableValue = ko.utils.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        initEditor(element, observableValue, allBindingsAccessor);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var observableValue = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        createEditor(codeEditorDiv, observableValue);
        resize();
        updateEditor(element, observableValue, allBindingsAccessor);
    }
};
```

And my HTML code is:

```
 <div id="editor" data-bind="editor: EditorVM"></div>
```

I am using [Dotnetify](http://dotnetify.net) for the ViewModel so it is a reasonable complex C# class, but suffice it to say that the binding is working and updating, but I need it to only call 'update' once all properties have been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unfortunate you haven't shown what `initEditor`, `createEditor` and `updateEditor` do with the `observableValue`, because that's probably where you should be extending your observables.

The `init` and `update` methods of a binding create computed dependencies, meaning that *any* observable that is unwrapped in the call stack starting from `init` will cause the `update` method to be called.

In an abstract example:

```js
const someVM = ko.observable({
  a: ko.observable(1),
  b: ko.observable(2),
  c: ko.observable(3)
});

// Some function that unwraps properties
const logABC = function(vm) {
  console.log(
    vm.a(),
    vm.b(),
    vm.c()
  );
}

// Regular binding update:
ko.computed(function update() {
  console.log(
    "Regular binding update:",
  )
  logABC(someVM())
});

// Change VM
someVM(someVM());

// Change a, b, and c
someVM().a("A");
someVM().b("B");
someVM().c("C");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Note that `update` is called:

1. When initializing the computed
2. When changing the observable that contains the viewmodel
3. When changing *any* of the observable properties of the viewmodel

There are several ways of solving the issue, of which the simplest is to create your own `computed` inside the `init` method of your binding and extend it to be `deferred`.

```js
const someVM = ko.observable({
  a: ko.observable(1),
  b: ko.observable(2),
  c: ko.observable(3)
});

const getABC = function(vm) {
  return [vm.a(), vm.b(), vm.c()].join(", ");
}

ko.bindingHandlers.renderABC = {
  init: function(el, va) {
    el.innerText += "Init.\n";
    
    // This ensures any inner unwrapping gets deferred
    var updateSub = ko.computed(function update() {
      el.innerText += getABC(ko.unwrap(va())) + "\n";
    }).extend({ deferred: true });
    
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(el, function() {
      updateSub.dispose();
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({ someVM: someVM });

// Change VM
someVM(someVM());

// Change a, b, and c
someVM().a("A");
someVM().b("B");
someVM().c("C");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<pre data-bind="renderABC: someVM"></pre>
```

Comment: How is `updateSub` being applied to the binding? All my `xEditor` methods do is take the unwrapped accessor and apply the properties inside to another plugin, hence what is happening is `update` is being called once for *every* property that gets changed, rather than once for the entire object.

Comment: The `updateSub` computation is added as a deferred dependency to *all* of the observable properties your `xEditor` methods unwrap. Because I'm manually creating it, I can extend it to be deferred. If we were to rely on the `update` method provided by the binding, we'd get an update for every change since there's no way to defer it.

Comment: Ah. It's the `update` function *inside* the computed using the outer `valueAccessor` that was the bit I was missing. That doesn't appear to be anywhere in the Knockout docs. Adding that in works perfectly and only calls the `update` once the entire VM is updated. Thanks.